# Responsive design works on simulators but not on phones

Tags: responsive-design

I have created a website (splash page really) that should be responsive.  I have tested it on several simulators and they say it works fine.  But when I view on my iphone, it doesn't.  Could someone look at the site [fytme.us](http://fytme.us) and see what might be the problem.

Thanks.

Comment: Try simulating in iphone configurations

Comment: I did that and it works in my simulations.  But not on my phone.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17275452/media-queries-working-in-chrome-but-not-safari-ie-or-firefox

Comment: I have a space after the "and".  Any other thoughts?